# Beautifulsoup find_all doesn't find out elements without data_reactid

Tags: beautifulsoup

[element w/ and w/o data_reactid attr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6i0MX.png)

In this case, if I use the below code, I can only find the first 3 that have data-reactid, the rest 4 are ignored, why?

```
headers = {
'accept': '*/*',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
 AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36'
}
response  = requests.get(url_finNews, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
items = soup.find_all('li', {'class':'js-stream-content Pos(r)'}
print(len(items))
```

The result is 3 (all of reactid) instead of 7. Does anyone run into the same problem? Thanks!

Comment: How did you fetch the html?  Did you do something like `requests.get()`?

Comment: Sure, I have these code at the beginning...        response  = requests.get(url, headers=headers) and 
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

Comment: How did you get the html code in that screenshot?  Was that in a regular browser?  If so, then the problem is likely due to those extra elements being created by javascript.  The `requests` module can't do javascript.